# Site Content Publishing error

Tags: cross-site-publishing, site-contents

I am trying to set some site contents but I am unable to publish due to `'No Proxy can be found to do this operation. '`

Does any one know how to fix it in simple terms?

Please as I am very green to SharePoint and the fickle settings.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

check these items:

1. Make sure that Managed Metadata Service proxy associated with the web app.( Central admin > Application management > web app and from ribbon select service connection)
2. Check if 'Managed Metadata Service' service is running on server(s). ( Central admin > Managed Services on server.)
3. Browse Managed Metadata Service from Service Applications, if working correctly
4. IIS reset on servers

Check this [POST](https://sharepoint-for-real.blogspot.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-content-type-publishing.html).